# I cannot workout how to use a Partial View in a form that uses Knockout in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

This is my view;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SHP.Models.TrainingListEmployeesViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="SHP.Helpers" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Bulk Training
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<form class="employeeListEditor" data-bind="submit: save">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Allocate or cancel training for the selected employees</legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Course Name</td>
            <td><%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainingName)%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Description (optional)</td>
            <td><%:
           Html.TextAreaFor(
               model => model.TrainingDescription, new { maxlength = "255", style = "width:400px;height:100px;" })%></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientEmployeeSelector)%>
    <button id="btnAdd" data-bind="click: addEmployee">Add</button><button data-bind="click: clearEmployee">Clear</button>
    <div id="displayEmployees" style="margin-top:10px;" data-bind="visible: employees().length > 0">
        <table id="employeeDataTable" class="groupBorder">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeEmployee">Remove</a>
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: SearchTextId"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: SearchText"></span></td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="employeeCalendar">
        <% if(Model.Cvm != null)
           {%>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Calendar", Model.Cvm); %>
            <div><span style="margin-top: 10px"></span></div>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;">
                <div style="display: inline; margin-right:20px; padding:5px;">
                    <%:Html.MakePopupForm<SHP.Controllers.LeaveController>(o => o.TrainingSingleDate(), refreshOnSuccess: true)%>
                    <%:Html.PopupFormActionLink<SHP.Controllers.LeaveController>(o => o.TrainingSingleDate(), "Add a single date")%>
                </div>
            </div>    
            <% if (TempData["SuccessMessage"].ToSafeString().Length > 0)
               {%>
                    <p class="success" style="padding-top: 20px;"><%: TempData["SuccessMessage"].ToSafeString() %></p>
            <% } %>     
        <% }%>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Employee(id, text) {
            var self = this;
            self.SearchTextId = ko.observable(id);
            self.SearchText = ko.observable(text);
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {         
            $('#SearchText').attr("data-bind", "value: autocompleteSearchText");
            $('#SearchTextId').attr("data-bind", "value: autocompleteSearchTextId");
            $("#TrainingName").attr("data-bind", "value: trainingName");
            $("#TrainingDescription").attr("data-bind", "value: trainingDescription");

            var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
            var autocompleteData = { "autocompleteSearchTextId": 0, "autocompleteSearchText": null };
            function viewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.employees = ko.observableArray(initialData.EmployeeList);
                self.trainingName = ko.observable(initialData.TrainingName);
                self.trainingDescription = ko.observable(initialData.TrainingDescription);
                self.autocompleteSearchText = ko.observable(autocompleteData.autocompleteSearchText);
                self.autocompleteSearchTextId = ko.observable(autocompleteData.autocompleteSearchTextId);
                self.removeEmployee = function(employee) {
                    $("#btnAdd").after("<span class='error'>Please wait for calendar update ...</span>");
                    self.employees.remove(employee);
                    self.save();
                };
                self.clearEmployee = function() {
                    self.autocompleteSearchText('');
                };
                self.addEmployee = function() {
                    $("#btnAdd").after("<span class='error'>Please wait for calendar update ...</span>");
                    self.employees.push(new Employee(self.autocompleteSearchTextId(), self.autocompleteSearchText()));
                    self.autocompleteSearchText('');
                    self.save();
                };
                self.save = function() {
                    var list = ko.toJS(self.employees);
                    var name = ko.toJS(self.trainingName);
                    var description = ko.toJS(self.trainingDescription);
                    ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { employees: list, trainingName: name, trainingDescription: description });
                };
            }   
            ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

You may notice I have a popup form in this view. 
Also I would like to put all the code in the employeeCalendar div in a partial view.
Because of the popup window, I have to make sure in my controller that I redirect my Post method to my Get method so that when the popup data input has been completed and undates this view, I do not get an unwanted resend message  from windows.
The problem with doing these redirects is that I get a full page postback that looks unpleasent. So I would prefer to refresh my claendar from a partial view via Ajax.
So how do I do this?
This is my controller

```
   [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Trainer, ManagerAccounts, ManagerIT")]
    public ActionResult BulkTraining()
    {
        if (SessionObjects.Tlevm == null)
        {
            return this.View(new TrainingListEmployeesViewModel());
        }

        return this.View(new TrainingListEmployeesViewModel(
            SessionObjects.Tlevm.EmployeeList,
            SessionObjects.TrainingName,
            SessionObjects.TrainingDescription));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Trainer, ManagerAccounts, ManagerIT")]
    public ActionResult BulkTraining([FromJson] IEnumerable<ClientEmployeeSelector> employees, string trainingName, string trainingDescription)
    {
        // Items stored in Session used when saving the training dates for the employee
        // via the popup window
        SessionObjects.TrainingName = trainingName.JsonTrim();
        SessionObjects.TrainingDescription = trainingDescription.JsonTrim();
        SessionObjects.EmployeeIdList = employees.Select(x => x.SearchTextId).ToList();
        SessionObjects.EmployeeNameList = SessionObjects.EmployeeIdList.Count > 0
                        ? Employee.GetNameList(SessionObjects.EmployeeIdList)
                        : string.Empty;
        SessionObjects.Tlevm = new TrainingListEmployeesViewModel(
            employees.ToList(),
            SessionObjects.TrainingName,
            SessionObjects.TrainingDescription);
        return this.RedirectToAction("BulkTraining");
    }
```

Comment: Whats with the `asp:Content` tag?

Comment: Why on earth are you using the aspx view engine rather than the razor view engine?

Comment: it was originally written in MVC 2 and it has not been upgraded.

Comment: If you want a Partial View, then you will need to return a PartialView in your controller - at least that's how it works in MVC3+.